# Extracting text outside of a <div> tag BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

So Im practicing my scraping and I came across something like this:

```
<div class="profileDetail">
    <div class="profileLabel">Mobile : </div>
     021 427 399 
</div>
```

and I need the number outside of the `<div>` tag:

My code is:

```
num = soup.find("div",{"class":"profileLabel"}).text
```

but the output of that is `Mobile :` only it's the text inside the `<div>` tag not the text outside of it.

so how do we extract the text outside of the `<div>` tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would make a *reusable function* to get the value by label, finding the label by `text` and getting the [next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
import re

def find_by_label(soup, label):
    return soup.find("div", text=re.compile(label)).next_sibling
```

Usage:

```
find_by_label(soup, "Mobile").strip()  # prints "021 427 399"
```

Comment: why does it work using re.compile? but not when `text="Mobile"` thats really odd

Comment: Because the `re` stands for regular expression, it matches part of a string where as `text='Mobile'` searches for the whole text to be 'Mobile'

Comment: @Crispy know what re stands for hehe. actually the reason why it doesn't show is because I inputted it wrong. it should be text="Mobile : " with the colon and spaces. I tested it out again without re.compile and well it worked

Answer (score 3):

try using `soup.find("div",{"class":"profileLabel"}).next_sibling`, this will grab the next element, which can be either a `bs4.Tag` or a `bs4.NavigableString`.

`bs4.NavigableString` is what your trying to get in this case.

```
elem = soup.find("div",{"class":"profileLabel"}).next_sibling
print type(elem)

# Should return
bs4.element.NavigableString
```

#### Example:

```
In [4]: s = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<div> Hello </div>HiThere<p>next_items</p>', 'html5lib')

In [5]: s
Out[5]: <html><head></head><body><div> Hello </div>HiThere<p>next_items</p></body></html>

In [6]: s.div
Out[6]: <div> Hello </div>

In [7]: s.div.next_sibling
Out[7]: u'HiThere'

In [8]: type(s.div.next_sibling)
Out[8]: bs4.element.NavigableString
```

Answer (score 1):

For future readers that feel this wasn't what they wanted, this may be your answer:

```
for tags in soup.find_all('div'):
    if "profileLabel" in tags['class']:
      print(tags.contents[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this alternative solution! To help those future readers, can you explain what this solution does differently than the other answers?